# Autodesk forge transalte rvt to IFC and moving in to folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am using [model derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) to Translate from .rvt to IFC. I managed to do that successfully, but I am wondering if there is any way to move the translated IFC file to a specific folder in BIM360 without downloading it and uploading it again to BIM360?

Comment: I [asked](https://autodesk.slack.com/archives/C12EGMUK0/p1629271491013300) the development team for you... hang on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move files within the same account & project using the following endpoint - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/

Pay attention to the the query string parameter in that section - [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/#query-string-parameters)

And also there is a blog post which shows other possible workflows - [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/move-files-around-forge)